# JavaFX Video Stutter (MediaView)

Tags: java, video, javafx, video-player

So I've been running into an issue lately. Whenever I want to play a videofile with JavaFX MediaPlayer combined with MediaView the video seems to stutter all over the place. I tried different types of videofiles (I rendered most of them myself as .mp4 with h264 encoding) where framerates range from 30fps to 60fps, the bitrate being 14.000.000 to 28.000.000 bps.

The lag also occurs with most files that I haven't rendered myself, so I'm quite sure that there is nothing wrong with my renderings.

*edit*
Further testing confirmed that it does not matter that I rendered the videofiles myself.

**Do you guys know why this videostutter might be occuring and how to fix it?** I'm open to any type of fixes, including using different ways of displaying the videofiles other than through JavaFX. Here is the main code of the videoplayer:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends JPanel implements Checkable
{
    private MediaView view;
    public JFXPanel pane;
    private String path;
    public MediaPlayer player;
    private Dimension size;
    public VideoPlayer(String path, Dimension size)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.path = path;
        pane = new  JFXPanel();
        player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(path));

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 initFX(pane);
             }
         });
        pane.setPreferredSize(size);
        pane.setSize(size);
        pane.setLocation(0,0);
        add(pane);

    }

    public void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = createScene();

        pane.setScene(scene);
    }

    private Scene createScene()
    {
       view = new MediaView();
       view.setMediaPlayer(player);
       Group root = new Group();
       view.setPreserveRatio(true);
       view.setFitWidth(size.width);
       view.setSmooth(false);
       root.getChildren().add(view);
       Scene scene = null;

       try{
            scene = new Scene(root, size.width, size.height)
       ;}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        return scene;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        player.play();
    }
}
```

Here, the videoplayer receives a String with the path to the videofile, the Dimension size is the size the player should be.

The class itself extends JPanel so that it can be added to a JFrame. This JPanel contains a JFXPanel which in its turn contains the MediaView.

If you guys can figgure out why the video is getting stutter it would be amazing. I'm open to all solutions!

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Edits**
As suggested by @AlmasB I made a bare-bone pure JavaFX application to play the exact same files. It might have reduced stutter by a tiny amount, but perhaps not at all. It was very hard to see wether it was better or not. Here is the code of the bare-bones JavaFX videoplayer:

```
public class VideoPlayerTest extends Application {
    static MediaView view;
    static MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        //root.getChildren().add(btn);
        makeMediaView();
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        player.play();


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1920, 1080);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private static void makeMediaView(){
        player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("file:///C:/Users/wesse/Documents/CowLite%20GabenQuest/resources/cutscenes/gabenquestepisode1intro.mp4.old"));
        view = new MediaView(player);
        view.setPreserveRatio(true);
        view.setFitWidth(1920);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

As suggested by @AlmasB some info:

*System info*

Windows 10

Latest JDK version (1.8)

gtx960, intel i5 3470, 8gb RAM

*video tests*

1080p 60fps 28mbit/s *stutter*

1080p 30fps 14mbit/s *stutter*

720p 29fps 1.8mbit/s **no stutter, but poor video quality due to low bitrate/resolution, downloaded from YT**

1080p 60fps 5.3mbit/s **very slight stutter, decent video quality, downloaded from YT**

1080p 60fps 6.3mbit/s *medium stutter, perfect quality, self rendered*

**I'm rendering some videos myself now with lower bitrate to see if this is the problem.**

Comment: Why are you mixing `swing` and `javafx`?

Comment: @hotzst The VideoPlayer is a utility class used to play cutscenes in a game I'm creating as a fun sideproject. The game itself was created fully in Swing, and the cutscenes were implemented later on. Is it problematic that I combine Swing and javafx?

Comment: @ImJustACowLol first try a minimal JavaFX app that has only the objects required to play the video. See if that makes any difference. If yes, you will need to rewrite how you use `MediaView`, probably by using separate application which is tied to the main one and switch between windows. If the stutter remains even in the minimal application, that means the codec or your machine is just slow for the video decoding.

Comment: @AlmasB The hardware should definitely not be the issue, I have a gtx960, 8gb of RAM and a i5 3470 processor. I'll try rewriting it into a small JFX Application to  see if that helps. Concerning codecs: Are there any codecs you recommend installing? And shouldn't other videoplayer programmes also suffer due to the codec?

Comment: @AlmasB Making a seperate bare-bone JavaFX application did not reduce the stutter by a visible amount. I could hardly tell if it improved or not. Do you have any other suggestions? And regarding the video codecs: I had a clean reïnstall of windows about a month and a half ago, and I haven't installed any custom codecs. I did install VLC (not sure if that comes with any).

Comment: @ImJustACowLol How about the video resolution? Try playing something which lasts ~30sec at 800x600 with 30fps or similar configuration. Also copying some info might help, e.g. OS, JDK

Comment: @AlmasB Some system info & additional tests have been updated. It might be that the video bitrate is the culprit.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol Yes, that's why I suggested a bit less demanding configuration, to see if it makes any difference. For in-game video I usually use 720P, 2-3mbits @ 30fps with a very smooth playback. So you might have to play around with video settings

Comment: @AlmasB It might be that the videocodec is the problem... Just made a 30fps 1080p 3.5mbit/s file which also stutters. I use the Sony Vegas AVC/AAC rendering settings... Lets fiddle around with that too. Meanwhile I'll try uploading & then downloading the video to and from youtube to see if the codec is the issue (YouTube converts it).

Comment: @AlmasB Looks like the codec is the issue. Just downloaded the video from YouTube, 1080p, 4mbit/s, 60fps, and it runs perfectly smooth. Gonna have to figgure out what the best codec is.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol Glad the issue is narrowed down. I use h.264/mpeg-4 avc from Xilisoft video converter if it's of any use

Comment: @AlmasB Do you convert your videos after rendering them, or can you immediatly render with it? I am using Sony Vegas pro 12 and I'm not sure how to add new mp4 codecs. Whichever ones I install land under 'videos for windows' which is .avi, but I need the videos to be .mp4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124120/discussion-between-almasb-and-imjustacowlol).